# Order of tasks to do to create a schema on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I have the schema for some tables that I should create in my rails project, Wanted to make sure this is the correct way of doing this:

- **1:** I can use `rails generate model` to create the preliminary schema
- **2:** Then I should go to models and manually hand type more dependencies that I need like foreign keys, validators on some fields,etc
- **3:** Go to Route.rb and exclude the routes that I don't need. ( It is the service part of an app, based on requirements I mostly need GET only ).
- **4:** Go to controllers, I need them just to return json, so I should modify them for that, adding some ActiveRecord code to also take care of those one to many tables that I had in model too.

Is there anything else I am missing? or better ways of doing this?

Comment: Are you asking about a schema file?  As in `db/schema.rb`?  It seems to me that you are asking whether there are any obvious steps that you are missing to setup a basic rails application?

Comment: no, the schema that we cretae on paper as for our Database schema like MySQL schema, I have that and wanted to get started on building it in Rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly correct, but a few things:

- You can add foreign keys to the table when you create the rest of the model with `rails generate model`.  You'll then need to create the *association* in the model file (i.e. `belongs_to` or `has_many`). You'll also want to create a migration that makes that key an index (for speed purposes).  As you said in your comment though, you can always adjust and edit models with migrations, as long as you then run `db:migrate` again.
- Neither routes nor controllers are not created when you run `rails generate model`.  Those are only generated along with the model are only created when you create a **scaffold** (i.e. `rails generate scaffold`).  You'll need to manually add the routes yourself, and can run `rails generate controller` (or just create the files yourself), if you're not using scaffold.

Comment: Thanks, can I just create the bare bones model with rails generate model and then later that I learned more about foreign keys and associations, I add them manually? and run a db:migrate again?

Comment: yes, that's correct.  Associations won't require the `db:migrate`, but the migration to add the keys to the tables will.  Of course, associations won't work without the foreign keys being present. (I edited the answer to reflect this)